# Google App Engine Channel API quota

Tags: google-app-engine, channel, channel-api

I know that there are similar questions, but they aren't up to date anymore. I'd like to know how much it costs to create 1 / 10 / 100 / 1000 channels per day? I only find the [pricing list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing), which doesn't mention channels, and the [quota list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Channel), which only says "depends on your budget".

I run out of quota really fast. If users access your website only for a short time, then creating 100 channels isn't enough (all other quotas are still 0%). I also read, that reusing channels isn't possible.

Channels are available for two hours. After that they are released. Does the quota mean: "You are only allowed to create 100 channel per day" or does it mean: "You are only allowed to have 100 channels at the same time"?

There is also an API do define when a channel should be released. Does this API even make sense? Let's say I choose to release the channel after one minutes. So while using browsing my website for 5 minutes, the user would create 5 different channels. Does it make sense to decrease the release time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- It costs 10,000 micropennies to create a channel (or 100 channels per 1 cent, see [appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) for more)
- You shouldn't create more than 1 channel per user.
- The free quota says you are only allowed to create 100 channels per day. Enable billing to get more.
- I wasn't aware about a possibility of releasing channels and not really sure what is the purpose of doing that and since they are so expensive to create anyway - it's probably better to reuse for the same user in case they return.